# Windows text-select cursor randomly doubled in length, makes selecting text quickly very difficult

Tags: windows, mouse, cursor

I was writing some code today when suddenly the length of my text select cursor doubled.  I figured it was some weird glitch so I restarted my computer but it didn't affect anything.  I checked in my Mouse settings and currently under text select it's still showing the same old default text select cursor.

I have no idea what could have caused this to happen, but it sure makes highlighting lines of code a pain.

Anyone know what the issue is?

[image]

Comment: Has the cursor size doubled for other applications too, or just your coding software?

Comment: @misha256 It's changed globally.  Any and all programs.

Answer (score 0):

Oh oh, I smell a dodgy Windows Update!

So... do you have Automatic Updates enabled, or have you done some manual updates yourself around the time this happened?

Perhaps an NVIDIA graphics driver was updated?

I have found another person [experiencing similar issues to you](http://www.tenforums.com/general-discussion/8279-mouse-cursor-has-randomly-enlarged-has-lines-going-through.html) and it's NVIDIA's fault.

> Nvidia has admitted it is a problem with their driver and are working on a fix for it as we speak.